# C# Reading file and pulling out specific lines

Tags: c#

Thanks in advance.  What i currently have is a filedialog box selecting a text file.  The text file contents will look like example.txt, and it needs to look like output.txt. NOTE: the string `CoreDBConnectString=` is 1 line all the way to `;Database=Source_DB.`

```
example.txt
[Information]
Date=
CreatedBy=
Unique=eqwe-asd-123-as12-3
CoreDataSource=
CoreDBConnectString=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=Server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Source_DB
NoteDataSource=SQLServer
NoteDBConnectString=Provider=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=Server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Source_DB
CoreDBCaseID=99
NoteDBCaseID=99


Output.txt
Table=99  (Comes from CoreDBCaseID)
Server=Server (comes from the string CoreDBConnectString=)
Security=SSPI (comes from the string CoreDBConnectString=)
Database=Source_DB (comes from the string CoreDBConnectString=)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// Load the file contents
string contents = File.ReadAllText("example.txt");

// Obtain the data using regular expressions
string id = string id = Regex.Match(
    contents, 
    @"CoreDBCaseID=(?<id>\d+)").Groups["id"].Value;

string server = string.Empty; // Add regex here
string security = string.Empty; // Add regex here
string database = string.Empty; // Add regex here

// Save the data in the new format
string[] data = new string[] {
    String.Format("Table={0}", id),
    String.Format("Server={0}", server),
    String.Format("Security={0}", security),
    String.Format("Database={0}", database)
};

File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", data);
```

And a quick way to learn those regular expressions:

[Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

---

You can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to stop matching at the (;) character. Something like this:

@"Security=(?[\D]+)(?=;)"

Comment: This works great, I am very new at Regex, and i worked out the following.

string security = Regex.Match(contents, @"Security=(?<Security>\D+)").Groups["Security"].Value;

this makes the following:
Security=SSPI;Database=GSK_DRP_Paxil_SSECase

How do I make the Regex cut off at ;
so i would get Security=SSPI

But it worked great!

Answer (score 2):

That is an INI file, which is very old school. Nowadays, we programming folks use XML instead. Consequently, there is no built-in support for INI files in C#.

You can [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileString.html) [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353(vs.85).aspx) to read the data.

You can use [WritePrivateProfileString](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WritePrivateProfileString.html) to write the new data out if you don't mind the information section header like so :

```
[Information]
Table=99
Server=Server 
Security=SSPI 
Database=Source_DB
```

[This CodeProject article on INI-file handling with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_ini.aspx) may help.

Comment: We also use condescension and prefer to omit punctuation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) and [`RegEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to read each line and extract the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and read it in one line at a time.  You can use Regular Expressions [(cheat sheet)](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) to match and parse only the text you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

INI files are old skool. Thus, someone has already written a class for it: [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/readwritexmlini.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_ini.aspx). The class linked reads XML, INI, Registry, and Config Files.